# Selenium Grid throws Parameter 'selenium.host' is required by @Configuration on method startServer

Tags: testng, selenium-grid

On running Selenium Grid I am getting the below exception:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'selenium.host' is required by @Configuration on method startServer
but has not been marked @Optional or defined in D:\workspace\ALM05_PA\config\gridSuite.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:144)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:342)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:78)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:191)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:131)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:278)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
```

My Code: (Consider i have started remote controls and launched the hub)

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({"selenium.host", "selenium.port", "selenium.browser", "selenium.url" })
public void startServer(String host, String port, String browser, String url, String SEARCH_STRING) throws Exception {      
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(host, Integer.parseInt(port), browser, url);
        selenium.start();
    }
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SL-Grid" parallel="tests">

    <parameter name="username" value="test" />
    <parameter name="password" value="test1" /> 

<test name="SL-Chrome" preserve-order="true"> 
    <parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.port" value="5555"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*googlechrome"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://properurl:8080/"></parameter> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.TestBase" /> // Base class where all generic methods, setUp and tearDown methods present
            <class name="com.Login"> // Login related methods and inherit TestBase
                <methods>
                    <include name="loginPage" />
                    <include name="signIn" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.Page1">
                <methods>               
                    <include name="clickLinkA" />
                    <include name="isTextBoxXXXPresent" />
</methods> </class></classes></test>

// same way for another browser we have another test with varied port number

</suite>
```

Difference between my project and other example given in various site are :
I have @BeforeSuite annotation in the startServer method, (@BeforeClass was not working for a normal project (not a Grid) as i have various inherited classes in a test and so i changed it to @BeforeSuite and its working.)

Can any one help me please.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see anything here that suggests you're using Selenium Grid.  What version are you trying to use?  What grid problem are you having?  It looks like you're just having problems starting an RC Server.

Comment: i am useing selenium-grid-1.0.8. For grid nothing specific we do except starting the hub and remote control... that i have launched and those details i have given in testng.xml (given one TEST example).. without grid i am able to run the same project (using another testng1.xml)

Comment: nirvdrum, you can even tell me why the below error occurs, thats enough and i can make it work: org.testng.TestNGException: Parameter 'selenium.host' is required by @Configuration on method startServer.. I could not make out the issue when i look at the code

Comment: Think your @BeforeSuite could be the problem. Try passing the selenium.host along with username and password parameters and see if the error is getting resolved

Comment: @nirvdrum, Can u please give me the way then if you know. AND i worked Grid based on the link, http://technologyandleadership.com/six-steps-for-complete-test-automation-with-selenium-grid/ and its worked well... here they used DefaultSelenium to start... the example used BeforeClass and i am using BeforeSuite.. that's the only difference and i believe that's why my application is not working..As i look the error and went through the forum i can see this is not Grid specific error... that's why i am asking any one can explain me why this error occurs and provide me the solution

Comment: @A.J, even i felt the same. but the code is for Grid i have to user these parameter independent for each Test. So i cannot declare it with username..

Comment: @Unni: Gotcha.  Sorry,  I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Using DefaultSelenium here does make sense.  It sounds like this is a TestNG problem.  Unfortunately I don't know much about that so I can't help.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Unni, thats exactly my point too. The problem that is happening here is you are calling startServer using "BeforeSuite" and it doesn't have any visibility to the parameter selenium.host - which is given under Test. And that is not a testNG bug. That's the way it is supposed to work I believe. I still didn't understand why you use BeforeSuite rather than "BeforeTest". Per your requirements, it should be "BeforeTest" I think.

Comment: Thanks A.J, Yes, I tried with "BeforeTest". BeforeTest works with my normal test suite.. but with Grid am getting repeatedly the below issues for various run which include 2 browsers. 1) ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet? (confirmed that RC is running- THIS PARTICULAR EXCEPTION ALWAYS OCCUR FOR ONE BROWSER RANDOM-WISE IN A RUN, which means only one browser at least start with an application and end up with the below issues, 2 & 3) 2) SeleniumException: Permission denied
3) java.lang.RuntimeException: result was neither 'true' nor 'false':

Comment: Now i figured out that Parallel run throw these error (ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?) but Sequential run works well by replacing parallel="tests" to <suite name="Suite" parallel="false"> .  Atleast Grid works sequentially and am relieved :)

Can you please figured out why parallel testing is getting failed with below exception for any one browser as stated earlier discussions: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?

Comment: can anyone please help me.. Parallel run is not working still..

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeTest` works for this setup..

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this doesnt solve it! any idea? :(