# Parameter 'google' is required by @Configuration on method setUp but has not been marked @Optional or defined

Tags: parameters, testng

There are couple of thread regarding same error but they are not active ,I think last they were active was around 1 yr back  so I am opening the new thread .

**Testng.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1">
    <parameter name="google" value="http://www.ezeego1.co.in/" />
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="selenium.karma.bu.DriverApp" />
            <class name="selenium.karma.bu.ReadSuite" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**DriverApp.java**:-

public class DriverApp {

```
public static WebDriver driver;

@Parameters("google")
@BeforeSuite
public void setUp(String appUrl) throws Exception{

    ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile p = prof.getProfile("default");
    p.setPreference("extensions.headertool.preferencies.editor", "sm_universalid: swkv8851\nftusergivenname: vidushi \nftusersn: shukla\nftapplicationroles: Admin\nftusercredentials: ES,PL\n\n");;
    p.setPreference("extensions.headertool.preferencies.onoff", true);

     driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://10.171.23.218:3080/karmaGui/karmaGui/KarmaGui.html?locale=en#Main") ;
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

And we have extended it to another java class readsuite.java.

When I execute my ReadSuite.java with testng I get following error:-

```
Total Rows Accross the sheets : 0
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'google' is required by @Configuration on method setUp but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\swkv8851\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1721497351\testng-customsuite.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:358)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

here

C:\Users\swkv8851\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--172149735`enter code here`1\testng-customsuite.xml get created at run time and it contents are

```
<suite name="Default suite">
    <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
        <classes>
            <class name="selenium.karma.bu.ReadSuite" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <!-- Default test -->
</suite>
<!-- Default suite -->
```

Please help me identifying the error.

When I comment @parameter and @Beforesuite in driverapp.java I do not get this error but then my browser is not invoked.

Comment: Hi Vidushi, welcome to SO. Existing questions do not need to be "active" in order for them to be useful to others. Can you link to the other answers you've found, and explain why they didn't help you, or specify why your problem is different from them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651725/how-to-use-testng-parameter-to-read-resource-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843575/selenium-grid-throws-parameter-selenium-host-is-required-by-configuration-on

I did try those solution but it didnot work for me..

Comment: Hmm, ok, it seems as though those questions aren't getting much love... hope you find someone who can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that TestNG created the testng.xml programatically because it can't find your testng.xml or you ran your *project* as a TestNG Test instead of your *testng.xml file*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run only your suite xml file, you need to select your suite file and select Run As-> TestNG Suite.

However, if you want to select a particular test and use the non test part of your suite file i.e. the suite/listeners/parameters section, then you can set this file as a template xml by going to Project Properties->TestNG -> Template XML File (give absolute path of your testng xml here)

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems to be a very old post, I am sharing the solution which worked for me.

Basically it requires two settings for TestNG Run 'Class' and 'Suite'

To set the TestNG Run 'Class'
Step1: Goto Project => Run As => Run Configurations => 'Test' tab
Step2: Check option 'Class'. It should be the set with desired '.java' file.
   e.g. 'functionalTestCases.java' is on package 'testCases' then 'Class' will be set as 'testCases.functionalTestCases.java'
Step3: Verify the 'Name' field. 
e.g It can be 'functionalTC'
Step4: Save the changes using 'Apply' button

To set the TestNG Run 'Suite'
Step1: Goto Project => Run As => Run Configurations => 'Test' tab
Step2: Check option 'Suite'. It should be the set with desired 'testng.xml' file path.
Step3: Verify the 'Name' field.
e.g It can be 'projectname_testng.xml'
Step4: Save the changes using 'Apply' button

After these setting are saved properly, then Run the project with 'projectname_testng.xml'

Also, I am using TestNG annotation as '@BeforeClass' for the method (which refers and checks the 'parameter' passed from 'testng.xml') in 'testCases.functionalTestCases.java'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to running as @Test.
You need to run it at Suite Level