# Is there a way to run a single @Parameters test without running xml file in TestNG Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have my tests with @Parameters annotations, and I can only run them by running the .xml file. If i right click a single class and try to run it I get the:

```
Parameter is required by @Configuration on method beforeClass but has not been marked @Optional or defined
```

I have the Parameters set up in the suite level of my xml, but still no success. Is there a way to run a single test only without creating an xml for it?

My Before class where parameters pass:

```
@BeforeClass
 @Parameters({"browser","environment"})
 public void beforeClass(String browser, String environment) {
 driver = Setup.Browser(browser, environment);
 }
```

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Regression">
 <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
 <parameter name="environment" value="qa1"/>
 <test name="Regression">



 <classes>
 <class name="Chrome.Logins_Users"/>
 </classes>

 </test>


</suite>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code and notify me? I've worked with selenium before but it's been a long time so I can't remember exactly how I used to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735283/parameter-google-is-required-by-configuration-on-method-setup-but-has-not-bee

Comment: updated the code above

Comment: Fixed with Shubham's link. Post the link as an answer Shubham and I will ward you the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set your xml in your preferences.  Set it up under `Project->Properties->TestNG-> template xml`.  Only the listeners and data under suite part would be used.